# Can you have an association based on a JSONB column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a Rails app (rails v6.0.3, ruby 2.7.1) that is using the [Noticed gem](https://github.com/excid3/noticed) to send notifications. I have the following model configuration:

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
    has_noticed_notifications
end
```

The `has_noticed_notifications` is, as described in their README, a "Helper for associating and destroying Notification records `where(params: {param_name.to_sym => self})`"

So when I create a Notification like so...

```rb
        VendorAddedNotification.with(
          vendor: vendor,
          data_source: "user",
        ).deliver(some_user) # => Notification inserted!
```

I expect to be able to find the Notifications that reference the vendor, using the Noticed method, like so:

```rb
vendor = Vendor.find ...
vendor.notifications_as_vendor # => Expected: [ Notification#123 ]
```

However, the input is always an empty array (`Actual => []`)

I looked at [their source code](https://github.com/excid3/noticed/blob/0cfcebe4c399fae8b5624235ba4641fc2c4ba153/lib/noticed/has_notifications.rb#L21) and it looks like `notifications_as_vendor` is the following query:

```rb
Notification.where(params: { :vendor => self }) # where self = an instance of the Vendor model
```

However, that doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure if it's supposed to or not. I tried running a simpler query to see if it worked ...

```rb
Notification.where(params: { :data_source => "user" })
```

But that did not work either. However, when I ran the same query with a different signature, it did:

```rb
Notification.where("params->>'data_source' = ?", "user")
```

So my question is-- is this Notified's mistake, or am I missing something in my configuration? I'm using PSQL for this, here is the relevant schema:

```rb
...
  create_table "notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "recipient_type", null: false
    t.bigint "recipient_id", null: false
    t.string "type", null: false
    t.jsonb "params"
    t.datetime "read_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["read_at"], name: "index_notifications_on_read_at"
    t.index ["recipient_type", "recipient_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_recipient_type_and_recipient_id"
  end

...
```

And here are the related models:

```
class VendorAddedNotification < Noticed::Base
  deliver_by :database

  param :vendor
  param :data_source
end

class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  include Noticed::Model
  belongs_to :recipient, polymorphic: true
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What sql query is vendor.notifications_as_vendor doing?

Comment: Hi @Joel_Blum , here it is:
`vendor.notifications_as_vendor.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"notifications\".* FROM \"notifications\" WHERE \"notifications\".\"params\" = '{\"vendor\":{\"_aj_globalid\":\"gid://stack-shine/Vendor/296\"},\"_aj_symbol_keys\":[\"vendor\"]}'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found why it's not working, it seems to be an issue with Notified.

In plain SQL I ran:

```sql
# PLAIN SQL
select "params" from "notifications" limit 1
```

Which returns the notification's params (returned notifcation's id=77)

```rb
# PLAIN SQL Result
"{""added_by"": {""_aj_globalid"": ""gid://stack-shine/WorkspaceMember/269""}, ""data_source"": ""user"", ""_aj_symbol_keys"": [""workspace_vendor"", ""data_source"", ""added_by""], ""workspace_vendor"": {""_aj_globalid"": ""gid://stack-shine/WorkspaceVendor/296""}}"
```

Now in Rails when I do

```rb
vendor = Notification.find(77).params[:vendor]
vendor.notifications_as_vendor.to_sql
```

The result is ...

```rb
"SELECT \"notifications\".* FROM \"notifications\" WHERE \"notifications\".\"params\" = '{\"vendor\":{\"_aj_globalid\":\"gid://stack-shine/Vendor/296\"},\"_aj_symbol_keys\":[\"vendor\"]}'"
```

... the extracted params from that query are:

```rb
'{\"vendor\":{\"_aj_globalid\":\"gid://stack-shine/Vendor/296\"},\"_aj_symbol_keys\":[\"vendor\"]}'
```

So ... In the database, the serialized params are A, but Rails is search for B:

```rb
# A: `params` In the database
"{""added_by"": {""_aj_globalid"": ""gid://stack-shine/WorkspaceMember/269""}, ""data_source"": ""user"", ""_aj_symbol_keys"": [""vendor"", ""data_source"", ""added_by""], ""vendor"": {""_aj_globalid"": ""gid://stack-shine/Vendor/296""}}"
# B: `params` Searched with by Rails
"{\"vendor\":{\"_aj_globalid\":\"gid://stack-shine/Vendor/296\"},\"_aj_symbol_keys\":[\"vendor\"]}"
```

Clearly this query could not work because the params in the database are not the params being search by Rails.

The notification, in the database, has extra parameters on top of "vendor" ("data_source" and "added_by") that are not being search up by the `Vendor`. Is this why it returns nothing?

For now, I'll simply the look up the notifications myself by storing the vendor_id in params and doing something like `Notification.where("params >> vendor_id = ?", 123)`